# putty mget by date

Tags: putty, mget

I am using putty via the command line to get (using mget) all of the txt files on a remote server.  I would like to only get the files for a specific date range or files that have not been previously downloaded.

**Edit:**  should have been more specific. I need to do this over an sftp connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really sounds like you'll want to look at [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/). See [Backing up Windows machines using rsync and ssh](http://aplawrence.com/Unixart/backup_rsync.html) by Manu Garg.

> *Economical backup solution: rsync and ssh*
>
> As all other unix tricks this is also the result of laziness and the need. I wanted to backup data on my windows laptop to a central linux/unix server. I didn't want all the features of available expensive backup solutions. Just a simple updated copy of my data on a central machine which is backed up to the tape daily. rsync is known for fast incremental transfer and was an obvious choice for the purpose.

Comment: This won't work for me because I don't have access to the server to install the rsycn daemon as the tutorial shows.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to script some form of retrieving remote file times, maybe parsing the output of the dir command.

Comment: rsync works over ssh just fine, you don't need to have the rsync daemon running.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to synchronize data?  If that is the case, perhaps try [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/)?